# Chrome version mismatch?

Tags: google-chrome, upgrade

I have Google Chrome ver. 41.0.2272.118 and I decided to upgrade it.

I've dowloaded latest version of Google Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 :

```
Got:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main google-chrome-stable amd64 46.0.2490.86-1 [47,3 MB]
```

Then I check version from console:

```
maxim@maxim:/opt/google/chrome$ ./google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 46.0.2490.86
```

But when I run it

```
maxim@maxim:/opt/google/chrome$ ./google-chrome
```

and check About, it still show **41.0.2272.118**

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this similar problem on Linux Mint. I found the following solution to work.

1. Close all Chrome sessions
2. Update google-chrome using apt-get as you have done above
3. Move the config files from ~/.config/google-chrome to ~/.config/bkp_google-chrome
4. Start google-chrome and the new version should now be started.
5. **Please note this will erase all your history, bookmarks etc**